# Infinite compositing in Java class?

Tags: java, oop

I am reading some code from this project: https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/ and I found something like this:

```
public class Translator {
    private static Translator translator;

    private Translator() {
    }

    public synchronized static Translator getInstance() {

        if (translator == null) {
            translator = new Translator();
        }
        return translator;

    }

    public void translate(TextTranslate textTranslate) throws APIError {

        Parse parse = new ParseTextTranslate(textTranslate);
        parse.parse();

    }

    public String translate(String text, String languageInput,
            String languageOutput) throws APIError {

        Text input = new Text(text, languageInput);
        TextTranslate textTranslate = new TextTranslate(input, languageOutput);
        Parse parse = new ParseTextTranslate(textTranslate);
        parse.parse();
        return textTranslate.getOutput().getText();

    }

    public String detect(String text) throws APIError {

        Text input = new Text(text);
        Parse parse = new ParseTextDetect(input);
        parse.parse();
        return input.getLanguage();

    }

}
```

So the class contains an instance of the same class, wouldn't there be infinite compositing?

Comment: Its a Singleton class.

Comment: "Infinite compositing" is a beautiful and poetic definition for a singleton class, actually :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no danger of "infinite composition" at all in Java. Even if you code

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    Node(){...}
    void setNext( Node x ){ next = x; }
    Node getNext(){ return next; }
}
```

you don't have one Node sitting in another Node like a set of Russian dolls. Remember: variables "storing an object" **do not contain** the object, which would live merrily on the heap. The variable (here: `next`) holds a **reference** to the object.

The sketchy Node class would result in a *chain* of Node objects, each *referencing* its next Node until one has `null` stored in `next`, that's the end.

Comment: It will also end the chain if one of the `Node`s references a `Node` that was earlier in the chain.

Comment: Yes, although this is rarely done. - Doubly linked circular lists are another matter.

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the famous design patters in java - **Singleton Class**. You can refer to the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on the same.

Also it does not led to infinite recurssive stack usage because constructor is private - you can never create a new instance of the class with new operator. Also the `translator` variable is just declared and is not initialized (in the constructor). Also you have a null check in `getInstance()` method which will ensure that the constructor is run only once in a JVM instance.  There will be only one instance of the class in JVM under **normal circumstances**.

Comment: Some would say »**infamous**« design patterns

Comment: Then I would reframe it as Famous design pattern used asked in interviews ;)

Comment: The fact that a constructor is private would not make it impossible to be recursive without termination, i.e., result in stack overflow:  `private Foo(){ Foo foo = new Fpp(); }` and add a method `createFoo`.

Comment: Agreed but that is not the case here. Also if you try to initialize instance of the same class in same constructor it will obviously give stack overflow error.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I wanted to write: `private Foo(){ Foo foo = new Foo(); }` but the typo made it sound silly. (The Foo foo on the left hand side should help to make that clear.) - Anyway, OP was fearing an infinite **composition** - not **recursion**.